# Issue with Jasmine installation on Rails 3.2

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, jasmine

I'm trying to install Jasmine on Rails 3.2 project using Jasmine gem.

I'm followed the instructions of gem install, but is not working.

Additional information: I'm using Vagrant.

When I try execute the rake, that is aborted:

This is the trace of my `rake jasmine`:

```
** Invoke jasmine (first_time)
** Invoke jasmine:server (first_time)
** Invoke jasmine:require (first_time)
** Execute jasmine:require
** Invoke jasmine:configure (first_time)
** Execute jasmine:configure
rake aborted!
undefined method `context_class' for nil:NilClass
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@lingo/gems/jasmine-2.0.0/lib/jasmine/config.rb:57:in `initialize_config'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@lingo/gems/jasmine-2.0.0/lib/jasmine/config.rb:75:in `config'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@lingo/gems/jasmine-2.0.0/lib/jasmine/config.rb:6:in `configure'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@lingo/gems/jasmine-2.0.0/lib/jasmine/config.rb:86:in `load_configuration_from_yaml'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@lingo/gems/jasmine-2.0.0/lib/jasmine/tasks/jasmine.rake:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@lingo/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@lingo/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@lingo/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@lingo/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => jasmine => jasmine:server => jasmine:configure
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put jasmine under the `development` and `test` groups in your Gemfile.